# How to rearrange objects within a list

Tags: r, list

Consider this example:

```
list1 <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl) 
names(list1)

[1] "4" "6" "8"
```

How can I rearrange the the objects within the list to `8, 4, 6` order

This should be a simple task and I simply can't seem to find an answer to it using google.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ronak Shah - clearly my question is a duplicate. I put-up mine having searched in vain via google. The difference I suppose is the way the previous question is worded "element" vs. "object" in my post. Happy for it to be deleted though...do i delete or does the mod deletes it?

Comment: No, it is okay to keep this question. Read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use a simpler list so its easier to see what's going on:

```
> list1 = list("4"="Four","6"="Six","8"="Eight")
> names(list1)
[1] "4" "6" "8"
> list1
$`4`
[1] "Four"

$`6`
[1] "Six"

$`8`
[1] "Eight"
```

Then reorder using single square brackets:

```
> list2 = list1[c("8","4","6")]
> list2
$`8`
[1] "Eight"

$`4`
[1] "Four"

$`6`
[1] "Six"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply provide a vector of indices of the elements in the order you want, in this case you want the third, followed by the first and second element:

```
list1 <- list1[c(3, 1, 2)]
```

This will produce:

```
names(list1)
[1] "8" "4" "6"
```

Comment: That doesn't rearrange the list, it rearranges the names. Do you need single square brackets or double square brackets to rearrange a list? Or is there a "reorder_list" function? Or something else?